# ModX Evolution: import external xml and create new pages

Tags: xml, parsing, new-operator, modx

Is it possible to automatically generate pages according to XML provided from another webpage?
Now I am using FeedX snippet to grab data from xml and parse them according to created template, but also have to create a new page for every item in XML...

Answer (score 0):

[FeedX](http://www.stanback.net/code/modx/feedx.html) is a plugin that can do it - but it hasn't been upgraded to Revo - which I'm in the process of upgrading now (and I'm waiting to hear from the author, otherwise, I'll just throw what I have on GitHub).

Comment: As I written, I am using Evo and FeedX, but it just not working or I dont know hot to implement it correctly... I have many (like 50 xml files to process)